How do I make the first 2 boxes selected by default?

Im new to react-native. I have created these selectors. Im stumped on how to make the default selection the first 2 items in each selector. So "Home Game" and "League" selected by default. Any ideas?
Here is my code
const SelectorBar: React.FC<Props> = ({
    value,
    labels,
    onChangeValue,
    style,
}) => {

    <View style={[styles.root, style]}>
            {
                labels && labels.map((item, index) => {
                    const isSelected = item === value;
                    const backgroundColor = isSelected ? colors.GREY.primary : 'transparent';

                    return (
                        <Pressable style={[styles.tab, { backgroundColor }]} key={index} onPress={() => { onChangeValue && onChangeValue(item); }}>
                            <CustomText>{item}</CustomText>
                        </Pressable>
                    );
                })
            }
        </View>
    );
};


You need to set the initial state for the value prop to include those default selections
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { View, Pressable, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
    import CustomText from './CustomText'; // Import your CustomText component
    import { colors } from './styles'; // Import your colors
    
    interface Props {
      value: string[];
      labels: string[];
      onChangeValue?: (value: string[]) => void;
      style?: object;
    }
    
    const SelectorBar: React.FC<Props> = ({ value, labels, onChangeValue, style }) => {
      const handlePress = (item: string) => {
        const isSelected = value.includes(item);
        const newValue = isSelected ? value.filter(v => v !== item) : [...value, item];
    
        if (onChangeValue) {
          onChangeValue(newValue);
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <View style={[styles.root, style]}>
          {labels &&
            labels.map((item, index) => {
              const isSelected = value.includes(item);
              const backgroundColor = isSelected ? colors.GREY.primary : 'transparent';
    
              return (
                <Pressable
                  style={[styles.tab, { backgroundColor }]}
                  key={index}
                  onPress={() => handlePress(item)}
                >
                  <CustomText>{item}</CustomText>
                </Pressable>
              );
            })}
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      root: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
      },
      tab: {
        padding: 10,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: colors.GREY.primary,
      },
    });
    
    export default SelectorBar;
    Use the SelectorBar component with default selections:
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { View } from 'react-native';
    import SelectorBar from './SelectorBar'; // Import your SelectorBar component
    
    const App = () => {
      const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState(['Home Game', 'League']);
    
      return (
        <View>
          <SelectorBar
            value={selectedValues}
            labels={['Home Game', 'Away Game']}
            onChangeValue={setSelectedValues}
          />
          <SelectorBar
            value={selectedValues}
            labels={['League', 'Playoffs', 'Tourney', 'Exhibition']}
            onChangeValue={setSelectedValues}
          />
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;

